# A cryptic riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> You do not know who made me, but I am made,
>
> You cannot see me, yet I am real,
>
> At one point I even surpassed Vegeta's power level,
>
> I sure have future too,
>
> You can get me by doing a common job during the industrial revolution,
>
> You can also get me online, using specialty websites,
>
> Finally, I have many lesser friends of my kind.

**Hint**

> This is a very "cryptic" answer.

Comment: Please don't make very minor edits to questions that have already been answered and Accepted. It bumps them back to the front page unnecessarily. (And if that's the point, then again, *don't* — that's an abuse of editing to keep an old post visible.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you...

> Bitcoin?

You do not know who made me, but I am made.

> The creator of bitcoin's true identity is unknown

You cannot see me, yet I am real.

> Bitcoin has no physical form

At one point I even surpassed Vegeta's power level.

> Bitcoin's highest valuation on "CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index" was [$19,783.21 on Dec. 17.](https://www.coindesk.com/900-20000-bitcoins-historic-2017-price-run-revisited/) while Vegeta's power level is 18,000

I sure have future too.

> Bitcoin has a futures market

You can get me by doing a common job during the industrial revolution.

> Bitcoin is created via mining

You can also get me online, using specialty websites.

> You can trade bitcoin using exchanges

Finally, I have many lesser friends of my kind.

> Various bitcoin clones exist

Regarding the hint:

> Bitcoin is crypto-currency, hence the quotation marks around cryptic

Comment: Great job! You get a green check!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> steam (/water vapor)?

You do not know who made me, but I am made

> Steam exists, but it's hard to define exactly what made it

You cannot see me, yet I am real

> You can't usually see water vapor (though you can sometimes...), but it's definitely real

At one point I even surpassed Vegeta's power points

> I don't know about this one

I sure have future too

> Water vapor will eventually condense, and - through the water cycle - have infinite future "lives"

You can get me by doing a common job during the industrial revolution

> Many jobs during the industrial revolution would have produced steam as a byproduct

You can also get me online, using specialty websites

> "Steam" is an online distribution platform for video games etc.

Finally I have many lesser friends of my kind

> Perhaps referring to the various forms of water (liquid, solid, etc.)?  Unsure why these would be "lesser" though.

Comment: Great answer, but unfortunately not correct. +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> Energy

You do not know what made me but I am made...

> we don't know how energy was made

You cannot see me, yet I am real

> We cannot see energy as it is not physical

At one point I even surpassed Vegeta's power points

> I'm guessing you are talking about Vegeta from Dragon Ball Z and energy has a LOT of power

I sure have future too

> Due to the law of conservation of energy, energy cannot be destroyed, therefore energy has a future

You can get me by doing a common job during the industrial revolution

> Since the factories required lots of energy to run, jobs such as coal mining were very common and produced energy

You can also get me online, using specialty websites

> Energy website

Finally I have many lesser friends of my kind

> There are many types of energy but they are all "sub types"

Comment: Good guess, but not correct